# Creating a table in Mysql dynamically with the AS SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry if it's a silly question, but I don't know how to create dynamically an SQL Table.
Let's imagine that I have two tables :

`Table1 : nameT1, numberT1, dateT1`

The first one isn't dynamically initiated. BUT the second needs to be, and the values in it have different names. So I started with this approach :

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
    nameT2 VARCHAR(20),
    numberT2 INTEGER(5),
    dateT2 DATETIME
) AS SELECT (
    nameT1,
    numberT1,
    dateT1
) FROM Table1;
```

But I have some problems with the compilation. And I don't know where I define that (for  Table2) :

```
nameT2 = nameT1
numberT2 = numberT1
dateT2 = dateT1
```

I simplified the problem, normally I have conditions to select which ones I want to insert from Table1 but that's not part of the problem.

Comment: Remove the brackets before the select and from

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do to make like the value of NameT1 goes into nameT2 ?

Comment: That's what your query will do once you remove the brackets as @P.Salmon said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A create as select will create the defined columns then append the selected columns. If you want to rename the columns drop the column definitions and use aliases. For example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;

CREATE TABLE T (nameT1 VARCHAR(3),numberT1 INT, dateT1 DATE);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('AAA',10,'2020-05-15');

CREATE TABLE T1  AS SELECT 
    nameT1 AS NAMET2,
    numberT1 AS NUMBERT2,
    dateT1 AS DATET2
 FROM T;

 SELECT * FROM T1;

+--------+----------+------------+
| NAMET2 | NUMBERT2 | DATET2     |
+--------+----------+------------+
| AAA    |       10 | 2020-05-15 |
+--------+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```